# Get 5 Items of an IEnumerable<KeyedList>

Tags: c#

I have an `IEnumerable<KeyedList<int, PictureItem>>`. What I want is that I get a new `IEnumerable<KeyedList<int, PictureItem>>` where only the first 5 Items in each KeyedList are selected.
At the moment I get every Item in the KeyedList.

UPDATE:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyedList<int, PictureItem>> GetFirstSixImages(IEnumerable<KeyedList<int, PictureItem>> pictures)
{
    var list = (from t in pictures
                select t.Item).Take(5);

    return list;
}
```

Here is the method I used

Comment: Use the Take() extension method, it lets you specify how many elements you want to take.  Take a look at the Enumerable class and learn *all* of the methods, they'll come in handy over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do something for all items, therefore you should use the `Select` function.
I do not know KeyedList, therefore I do not know how to construct a new KeyedList with some new items.

```
items.Select(keyedList => keyedList.Take(5));
```

provided that keyedList is `IEnumerable`.

just guessing, it could be something like:

```
items.Select(keyedList => new KeyedList<int, PictureItem>(keyedList.Take(5)));
```

The correct answer is (see the comment below)

```
 items.Select(keyedList => new KeyedList<int, PictureItem>(keyedList.Key,keyedList.Take(5)))
```

Comment: If I try your second code than I get this Error "1 argument: can not convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <PictureItem> "in" System.Linq.IGrouping <int,PictureItem> "."

Comment: could you give me a link to where KeyedList is documented, I might be able to help you better

Comment: I found the answer. I made it like this. pictures.Select(keyedList => new KeyedList<int, PictureItem>(keyedList.Key,keyedList.Take(5))); Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have you try Take(5).

Take is included in System.Linq namespace

Hope it is enough.

Comment: I have testet it. but than I get only the first Items of the Enumerable but I want 5 Items of the KeyedList in the IEnumerable

Comment: @newone Show us the code you've tried (edit your question to show it there).

Comment: Now I get you, then I think Ruben answer or something similar should work.